# Springboot Heroku app crashed while deploying

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Springboot heroku app but then I keep getting the error code H10 and status 503 and I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it. I've tried to delete the app and redeploy it but it doesn't work at all. How do I go about it? This is a screenshot of my log:

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykeRu.png)

Full project : https://github.com/sarthaksachdeva13/webdev-summer2-2018-server-java-sarthak

Answer (score 0):

In the log file I see `java.net.UnkownHostException: ${DBHOSTNAME}`. Looking at your `application.properties` file I see that you are using 4 environment variables (`DBHOSTNAME`, `DBSCHEMA`, `DBUSERNAME` and `DBPASSWORD`).

- Did you define all 4 environment variables in Heroko?
- Are you sure sure the value you defined for `DBHOSTNAME` is correct?